# Can't call action on second controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting a second Controller to operate.  I defined the first Controller and tested all of its methods with no problem.  When I tried to call a method on the second controller, I got the following error message:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:9801/api/defense/getgameopponents/seattle seahawks'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Defense' that matches the name 'get'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

My first controller - PlayerController.cs

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class PlayerController : ApiController
    {
         static readonly IPlayerRepository repository = new PlayerRepository();

    public List<Player> GetPlayers(string position, string teamName)
    {
        return PlayerController.repository.GetPlayers(position, teamName);
    }

    public List<Defense> GetPlayersPastOpponents(string position, string teamName, string playerName)
    {
        return PlayerController.repository.GetPlayerPastOpponents(new Player(playerName, teamName, position));
    }

    public List<Player> GetPlayerStats(string position, string teamName, string playerName)
    {
        return new List<Player>(){ PlayerController.repository.GetPlayerStats(new Player(playerName, teamName, position)) };
    }
}
```

}

The dysfunctional controller

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class DefenseController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IDefenseRepository repository = new DefenseRepository();

        string[] GetGameOpponents(string team)
        {
            return DefenseController.repository.GetGameOpponents(team);
        }

        Defense GetOpponentsStats(string teamName)
        {
            return DefenseController.repository.GetOpponentStats(new Defense(teamName));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, my routing table.  I have a strong feeling this is the issue, but I can't put my finger on it.  This is my first go at creating a project like this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  namespace Test
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetPlayerPastOpponentsApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{position}/{teamname}/{playername}"
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetPlayersApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{position}/{teamname}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetPlayerStatsApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{position}/{teamname}/{playername}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetGameOpponentsApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{team}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetOpponentsStatsApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{opponentname}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your missing the `public` designation on the action methods.

```
public /* <---THIS */ Defense GetOpponentsStats(string teamName)
{
    return DefenseController.repository.GetOpponentStats(new Defense(teamName));
}
```

Comment: You have saved me so much time and stress.  Thank you!  Can't believe I missed that difference.